# Intents value error in discord.py client subclass

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am new in creating bots for discord. Recently, while creating it, I chose to do it using Client Subclass to create my bot. I am running the latest version of **discord.py**

I have gone through the documentation but as I'm new being a developer on discord, I'm strugging to understand, how I can define my intents specifically on the bot.py file.

**Error Message**

```
    super().__init__()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'
```

**Client Subclass-method for my bot**

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):

  def __init__(self, model_name):
    super().__init__()
    self.api_endpoint = API_URL + model_name
    # retrieve the secret API token from the system environment
    huggingface_token = os.environ['HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN']
    # format the header in our request to Hugging Face
    self.request_headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(huggingface_token)
    }
```

**Triggering error code:**

```
def main():
  discord.Client = 
  client = MyClient('gpt-neo-2.7B')
  client.run(os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN'])
```

It'll be really helpful if anyone can help me to solve it. It looks to be a minor error but I'm new in the discord party : ) A help will be really appreciated!!

**Update**
New Error after Implementing Yevhen's solutions

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 87, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 83, in main
    client.run(os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN'])
  File "/home/runner/Kody/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Kody/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Kody/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Kody/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Kody/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/Kody/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 680, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 76a8f3be8fe2b05a &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-11-15 15:17:09 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">76a8f3be8fe2b05a</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">35.185.62.212</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script>(function(){var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'76a8f3be8fe2b05a',m:'.valzrok5r8KdLpyrEywT3cfvMXsLR9mX26smsSf2iI-1668525429-0-AV0i+x3Nod8qA9szB8ibIFDFwj9ztZ+VVdlGRKviap2e+CR6uK1HtGiXIAauXmkgI8aKn3O3/0q6aqgrD5QZcMFO3errmZE22j083egOJV4iAQhwSrfhPzP+kaN50NPYu4R5Yza4Y8P3yT0Fr2w04DY=',s:[0x17684d7afb,0x62974f07de],u:'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b'};var now=Date.now()/1000,offset=14400,ts=''+(Math.floor(now)-Math.floor(now%offset)),_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/scripts/alpha/invisible.js?ts='+ts,document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.nonce = '';_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

**Entire Code**

```
# the os module helps us access environment variables
# i.e., our API keys
import os

# these modules are for querying the Hugging Face model
import json
import requests

# the Discord Python API
import discord

API_URL = 'https://api-inference.huggingface.co/models/EleutherAI/gpt-neo-2.7B'


class MyClient(discord.Client):

  def __init__(self, model_name):
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    super().__init__(intents=intents)
    self.api_endpoint = API_URL + model_name
    # retrieve the secret API token from the system environment
    huggingface_token = os.environ['HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN']
    # format the header in our request to Hugging Face
    self.request_headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(huggingface_token)
    }

  def query(self, payload):
    """
        make request to the Hugging Face model API
        """
    data = json.dumps(payload)
    response = requests.request('POST',
                                self.api_endpoint,
                                headers=self.request_headers,
                                data=data)
    ret = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
    return ret

  async def on_ready(self):
    # print out information when the bot wakes up
    print('Logged in as')
    print(self.user.name)
    print(self.user.id)
    print('------')
    # send a request to the model without caring about the response
    # just so that the model wakes up and starts loading
    self.query({'inputs': {'text': 'Hello!'}})

  async def on_message(self, message):
    """
        this function is called whenever the bot sees a message in a channel
        """
    # ignore the message if it comes from the bot itself
    if message.author.id == self.user.id:
      return

    # form query payload with the content of the message
    payload = {'inputs': {'text': message.content}}

    # while the bot is waiting on a response from the model
    # set the its status as typing for user-friendliness
    async with message.channel.typing():
      response = self.query(payload)
    bot_response = response.get('generated_text', None)

    # we may get ill-formed response if the model hasn't fully loaded
    # or has timed out
    if not bot_response:
      if 'error' in response:
        bot_response = '`Error: {}`'.format(response['error'])
      else:
        bot_response = 'Hmm... something is not right.'

    # send the model's response to the Discord channel
    await message.channel.send(bot_response)


def main():
  client = MyClient('gpt-neo-2.7B')
  client.run(os.environ['DISCORD_TOKEN'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: You haven't included the last line of the error with an actual error message.

Comment: Gotcha! I have updated my question with my entire code and entire error message. Actualy the new error's last line was bunch of Script tags information that doesn't seem to indicate anything. But, I have included everything now.

Comment: The new error suggests you're spamming the API. Are you using replit or heroku by any chance?

Comment: I'm using replit :)

Comment: `Too Many Requests`, not sure if that is a permanent block. Try again later and don't run the script too often

Comment: Also use an async http library (like aiohttp) instead of requests. Using requests will freeze your whole bot.

Comment: @SleepingCat yep there's your issue. Everyone on replit shares the same IP address. Stop abusing their platform to run a bot, this is one of many issues you will encounter.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and all the suggestions @Yevhen and stijndcl. I wasn't running the bot, I was only testing it as some reason on my VS code discord bot isn't getting imported. But, will try to think of something :)

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests, `__init__` of `discord.Client` expects `intents` argument, so pass it in `super().__init__()`:

```
class MyClient(discord.Client):

  def __init__(self, model_name):
    intents = discord.Intents.default()
    intents.message_content = True
    super().__init__(intents=intents)
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had tried this trick but I got an error message. And it triggers a traceback while accessing the Discord Token. After reading in glance, seems to appear, it's conflicting with async library function. I have updated my question with the error. Can you check? : )